# Alter properties for multiple buttons at once

Tags: objective-c

I have this code to add borders to buttons, which has to be done to quite a few buttons.
Can I do this any easier without typing it out x times?

```
[self.button.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
[self.button.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[self.button.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding Multiple Property You can create Custom `UIButton` class. like create an class inherited `UIButton` like in `.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SLLabel : UIButton

@end
```

and add all required property into the implementation file like.

```
@implementation SLLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    //add your proerty here
    [self.button.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [self.button.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [self.button.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
}
@end
```

And then use you `CustomButton` as you use `UIButton` simply `#import` and Code.

Thanks